# VS code Built-in snippets not showing up (Javascript)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently my VScode my autocomplete is missing a lot of default option. Any Ideas what can cause this? All the default Built-in snippets won't work. Also user snippets won't show.

It just happendend randomly. Is this a bug in a recent update or is a settings?

This is my settings.json

```js
{
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact",
        "postcss": "css"
    },
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": true,
    "tslint.configFile": "/dev-gulp/.sass-lint.yml",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "scssLint.configDir": "/dev-gulp/.sass-lint.yml",
    "prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
    "sasslint.configFile": "/dev-gulp/.sass-lint.yml",
    "vsprettier.packageManager": "npm",
    "prettier.stylelintIntegration": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "activityBarBadge.background": "#64FFDA",
        "list.activeSelectionForeground": "#64FFDA",
        "list.inactiveSelectionForeground": "#64FFDA",
        "list.highlightForeground": "#64FFDA",
        "scrollbarSlider.activeBackground": "#64FFDA50",
        "editorSuggestWidget.highlightForeground": "#64FFDA",
        "textLink.foreground": "#64FFDA",
        "progressBar.background": "#64FFDA",
        "pickerGroup.foreground": "#64FFDA",
        "tab.activeBorder": "#64FFDA",
        "notificationLink.foreground": "#64FFDA",
        "editorWidget.resizeBorder": "#64FFDA",
        "editorWidget.border": "#64FFDA",
        "settings.modifiedItemIndicator": "#64FFDA",
        "settings.headerForeground": "#64FFDA",
        "panelTitle.activeBorder": "#64FFDA",
        "breadcrumb.activeSelectionForeground": "#64FFDA",
        "menu.selectionForeground": "#64FFDA",
        "menubar.selectionForeground": "#64FFDA",
        "editor.findMatchBorder": "#64FFDA",
        "selection.background": "#64FFDA40"
    },
    "materialTheme.accent": "Bright Teal",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterConstructor": true,
    "prettier.printWidth": 500,
    "html.format.wrapLineLength": 100,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "One Monokai",
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "svelte.enable-ts-plugin": true,
    "[svelte]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "svelte.svelte-vscode"
    },
    "svelte.plugin.svelte.note-new-transformation": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "chatgpt.chromiumPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
    "chatgpt.gpt3.apiKey": "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",
    "git.postCommitCommand": "push",
    "emmet.preferences": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    },
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": []
}
```

No loop example

[image]

No console.log example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [bug in snippets handling](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173244) reportedly fixed in yesterdays [update 1.75.1](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20milestone%3A%22January%202023%20Recovery%201%22%20is%3Aclosed).

Generally when facing some "blatant" issue, the updates page can give you some hints if there is some minor release:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates

Or sifting directly through GitHub Issues querying topic of your interest should be even more enlightening:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aissue+snippets

Usually when some "blatant" bug sneaks into stable release there is a flood of duplicate reports (sadly).